# Is there a simple explanation of how rdiff/rsync works?

Tags: rsync, rdiff

Imagine there are two very large files, e.g. Thunderbird e-mail folders, and then I apply rdiff (or rsync) to create a patch file that contains the differences between the two versions.

From molecular biology (DNA sequence aligning), I know you could shift the two files until the differences are the smallest:

```
do not use horses. attack at dawn.
maybe you could use horses. attack at dawn.
```

...aligns to:

```
         do not use horses. attack at dawn.
maybe you could use horses. attack at dawn.
```

...which gives you the content of the patch/diff file:

```
-{do not} +{maybe you could}
```

But it's computationally intensive to shift one file, several gigabytes large, byte for byte until you've found the best alignment. So, how does rdiff or rsync efficiently detect the largest agreement between two files, and work from there to create a reasonably small diff file?

Comment: The 5-step algorithm is given in https://rsync.samba.org/tech_report/ . The important detail is the rolling checksum.